# Interference pattern of an electron passing through a semislit instead through a single slit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, interference, double-slit-experiment

Is there a difference in the interference pattern of an electron between cases when it passes through a single slit and when it passes a "semislit", which I drew on the picture below to make it easier to understand.  Will the fact that the electron passes very close to a material cause waves that will move the electron in discrete directions to produce an interference pattern on the screen?  I am just asking about the physical concept of interaction between the electron and the material of the semislit.

[image]

Comment: What is "semislit" ?

Comment: [Deflection of electron beams at edges](https://www.academia.edu/27983554/Deflection_of_electron_beams_at_edges)

Comment: Why is this question closed?

Comment: Accelerated electrons emit billions of photons and they interact with a single edge To create a single edge Diffraction pattern, Which is different than a slit diffraction pattern.

Comment: The intensity at any point on the screen is based on the possible paths that the particle can take from the emitted location to that point. The semi-slit restricts some of those paths, so yes it will make a difference

Comment: @RC_23 All single edge patterns are the same depending only on the Photon frequency and distance between the edge and the detection screen. A slit produces two single edge diffraction patterns and overlaps them on the screen, creating an interference pattern. The single edge patterns are always there. See “Single Edge Certainty” at billalsept.com